# Why do singularities break the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals?

Tags: line-integrals, singularity

When doing a line integral in the field $\vec{F}=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\hat{i}+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\hat{j}$, the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals (FTOLI) **almost** always works because $\vec{F}$ is the gradient of $-arctan(\frac{x}{y})$.  This should mean that the line integral over a closed curve is $0$, but this doesn't work when the curve encloses the singularity at $(0,0)$.  Instead, the line integral over a closed curve needs to be evaluated without the FTOLI.

What I want to know is why a singularity messes up the FTOLI for a line integral around it.  Since the line integral doesn't pass through the singularity, why should it change anything?

Comment: Look at the proof of the fundamental theorem.  It uses Stokes' theorem, or Green's theorem, or Gauss' theorem or smilar: and it requires something to be defined not only on the curve, but also inside the curve.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields

Comment: I found a quick proof on Khan Academy (https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/line-integrals-in-vector-fields-articles/a/fundamental-theorem-of-line-integrals) which uses the multivariate chain rule.  This only considers the curve.  Also, the FTOLI works for curves which are not closed, so it seems like Green's theorem would not be the only way to prove it.

Comment: It almost works because $\phi(x, y) = -\arctan(x/y)$ is almost a potential for $\boldsymbol F$ :). An application of the gradient theorem would have to include the jumps $\phi(x, +0) - \phi(x, -0)$. If we have $\boldsymbol G = \nabla \psi$ with $\psi$ continuously differentiable on $D = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$, then indeed the gradient theorem gives $\int_\gamma \boldsymbol G \cdot d\boldsymbol s = 0$ for any closed curve $\gamma \subset D$.